# awk script to delete blocks in json

Tags: files, awk, json

I have a newline delimited JSON file with entries like this:

```
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2015.html","title":"Items where Year is 2015 - Ulster Institutional Repository","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2015.html"}
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2016.html","title":"Items where Year is 2016 - Ulster Institutional Repository","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2016.html"}
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2017.html","title":"Items where Year is 2017 - Ulster Institutional Repository","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2017.html"}
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10386/","title":"Structural performance of rotationally restrained steel columns in fire - Ulster Institutional Repos","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10386/"}
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10387/","title":"Determining the Effective Length of Fixed End Steel Columns in Fire - Ulster Institutional Repositor","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10387/"}
```

I only want blocks where the `.id` does not begin with `"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/"`

So if the script was run on the above code snippet, the first 3 blocks would be deleted and the only blocks remaining would be:

```
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10386/","title":"Structural performance of rotationally restrained steel columns in fire - Ulster Institutional Repos","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10386/"}
{"id":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10387/","title":"Determining the Effective Length of Fixed End Steel Columns in Fire - Ulster Institutional Repositor","url":"eprints.ulster.ac.uk/10387/"}
```

Can anybody help write an `awk` script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you specifically asked for an Awk solution:

```
awk -F\" '$4 !~ /eprints.ulster.ac.uk\/view/' file > newfile
```

Comment: This worked first time too thanks Jason. For future needs, it would also be helpful to run this as a regex which says ignore letters and only accept figures, i.e. something similar to: awk -F\" '$4 !~ /eprints.ulster.ac.uk\/[a-z]*/' file > newfile

Comment: This would be because I want to ignore urls such as /eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view or /eprints.ulster.ac.uk/author and only accept urls such as /eprints.ulster.ac.uk/16635

Comment: I achieved this with `awk -F\" '$4 !~ /eprints.ulster.ac.uk\/[[:alpha:]]/' uir-index.json > awk-cleaned-index.json`

Comment: @KoreMike you could also simplify if you only want digits with: `$4 ~ /eprints.ulster.ac.uk\/[[:digit:]]/`...

Comment: Note, though, that json is structured text and, like HTML or XML, can't be reliably parsed with just regular expressions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  The answer here works in this particular simple case but you really should get into the habit of using a specialised json parsing tool - one day you'll run into a json parsing job which you can't do with regexps and awk or sed.  `jq` as mentioned by others here is perfect for that job, it has been described as `sed for json`.

Comment: it's also worth noting here that both python and perl have excellent json handling libraries, as do many other languages.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
cat test.json| jq 'select(.id|startswith("eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/")|not )'
```

The syntax is quite simple if you are familiar with pipes.

For example

```
.id|startswith("eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/")|not
```

means that is takes the `.id` field of every object and pipe it through `startswith`,which returns a boolean and the boolean is negated.

Take a look at the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) from `jq` for more operators and selectors.

Comment: Worked first time! jq looks very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is interested I output Raphael's solution to a new JSON file with this command:

```
cat uir-index.json| jq 'select(.id|startswith("eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/")|not )' > cleaned-uir-index.json
```

The output format was back to multiline blocks of code. I ran the same jq command with the "--compact-output / -c" option like this:

```
cat uir-index.json| jq -c 'select(.id|startswith("eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/")|not )' > cleaned-uir-index.json
```

This output the cleaned file in newline format.